# AI in Microsoft Visual Studios 2015 that recognizes every word spoken and speak every word back

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, artificial-intelligence, voice-recognition

I am creating an AI in Microsoft Visual Studios 2015 and I am using the SpeechSytheizer object along with the SpeechRecognizer object instead of the speechRecognitionEngine object so that allowed me to use the Microsoft voice recognizer instead of the recognizer that is built into the SpeechRecognitionEngine so I do have to use grammarBuilders and load them into the SpeechRecognitionEngine.

With that being said, I have created a richTextBox that appends the words I say and recognized to the richtextBox; however, I am trying to have the ai say something back after I say something using:

```
if(e.result.text.toString().contains("whatever I said")){
s.speak("whatever i want it to say back");
}
```

however for some reason the microsoft voice recognizer doesnt sleep after I say something but appends the text but the ai doesnt saything back.

If anyone knows how to make the voice recognizer sleep once a sentence has been said and then have the speechSythesizer object say something back afterwards that would be great

Thanks, 
thatProgrammingGuy23

Heres the code so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    SpeechRecognizer rec = new SpeechRecognizer();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;
    }

    private void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {

        richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Result.Text.ToString() + "");

        if (e.Result.Text.Contains("hello")){
            s.Speak("hi");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Result.Text.ToString() + ""` can be simplified to `Result.Text` since Text is a string calling ToString() returns a identical string, also are you looking for `SpeechRecognizer.PauseRecognizerOnRecognition` ?

Comment: I believe you need to impeliment a keyword for activation, and a timer to control the amount of time it reads the voice. Then after the time window is closed you can use what ppl have said in the answers to disable the listening and do the narrating, if that's your problem...

Comment: Have you looked into Microsoft's bot framework? https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/bot-intelligence/speech/#navtitle

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `SpeechRecognizer` to ignore speech for a certain time you can use `SpeechRecognizer.Enabled`

```
SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer();
SpeechRecognizer rec = new SpeechRecognizer();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rec.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;
}

private void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Result.Text);

    if (e.Result.Text.Contains("hello"))
    {
        rec.Enabled = false;
        //Do stuff
        s.Speak("hi");
        rec.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What I'm wanting to do is say something to the speechRecognizer and then have that microsoft speech recognizer sleep while my ai speaks back to me and or do some sort of action and then start listening again as if it was like the speechRecognitionEngine.